# Razorflow Php error :A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, dashboard

RazorFlow PHP is a PHP Framework that you can use to build interactive data-driven dashboards which works across PCs, Macs, Tablets and Smartphones. 
There are 11 demo projects given in razorflow php. This is one of it. I would like to know how it works. I had check the path for razorflow.php and $dataSource.

```
<?php
require "../razorflow.php";
Dashboard::setTitle("Drill-down in same chart");

$dataSource = new SQLiteDataSource("databases/birt.sqlite");
$dataSource->setSQLSource("payments JOIN customers ON payments.customerNumber = customers.customerNumber");

$drillCategory = new ChartComponent();
$drillCategory->setWidth(4);
$drillCategory->setCaption("Drill-down by category", "Sales for {{value}}");
$drillCategory->setYAxis("Sales", array('numberPrefix' => "$"));
$drillCategory->setDataSource($dataSource);
$drillCategory->setLabelExpression("Location", "customers.country", array(
    'drillPath' => array('customers.country', 'customers.state', 'customers.city', 'customers.customerName')
));
$drillCategory->addSeries("Sales", "payments.amount", array(
    'displayType' => 'Column'
));
Dashboard::addComponent($drillCategory);

$drillTime = new ChartComponent();
$drillTime->setCaption("Drill-down by time", "Sales for {{value}}");
$drillTime->setYAxis("Sales", array('numberPrefix' => "$"));
$drillTime->setWidth(4);
$drillTime->setDataSource($dataSource);
$drillTime->setLabelExpression("Time", "payments.paymentDate", array(
    'timestampRange' => true,
    'autoDrill' => true
));
$drillTime->addSeries("Sales", "payments.amount", array(
    'displayType' => 'Column'
));
Dashboard::addComponent($drillTime);

Dashboard::Render();
```

But, I could not run this code successfully.  It always ends up with this error.

> Message:
>   A non well formed numeric value encountered                                                                           Trace:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\rf_4\core\internal\RFDbDataSource.php:86
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\rf_4\demos\chart_drilldown1.php:6

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $totalTime = microtime() - $startTime;
```

The error( A non well formed numeric value encountered) refer to code line above in RFDbDataSource.php.

> Microtime Return current Unix timestamp with microseconds.

The default value for microtime() parameter would be false. The result of microtime for true and false as parameter value:

```
microtime()     - as string 
microtime(true) - as float
```

Since , we doing substraction operation on microtime() value. microtime() should be float or numbers.So, change `microtime()` to `microtime(true)` able to solve the error( A non well formed numeric value encountered).